# In Subversion, how can I create a branch containing only part of the trunk?

Tags: svn, branch

I come from Git, so getting used to subversion after 12 years is taking some time:

I would like to create a branch that contains only a subset from my trunk, it is, only a subdirectory like

```
/project/trunk/source/component1
```

I've seen in the commit log some revisions that have achieved that, but from what I've read in the Subversion Redbook, using 'svn cp' command, will copy the whole trunk, something I don't want to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to perform the desired operation

```
svn copy --parents /project/trunk/source/component1/ /project/branches/branch1/trunk/source/component1/
```

This way a new branch is created, containing only the component1 contents. Next step is to commit with the commit command:

```
svn commit
```

So with only one (two) command(s) and one revision/commit I have a branch with the specific code subset.